# How can i get just the authors of a specific file from a git-repo?

Tags: git

I have a git-repo and need only the authors of a specific file. I can extract the authors from the git-blame command, but is there an easier way to get only the author names of a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git log --format=%an -- $file
```

will show you all commits for that file and only the authors for that commit. so you have one author per line

another easy solution would be to use `git shortlog`

```
git shortlog -s -- $file # add -n to sort by number of commits
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually what I want:

```
git log --format="%ad %an" -- $file
```

(includes the date of the commit)